# Load a module if it exists

Tags: requirejs

I tested the code below, but it does not work. I just tested whether the module is loaded.

```js
var Url=window.location.href;
var decomposedulr=Url.split("/");
console.log(decomposedulr);
var Getter=decomposedulr[decomposedulr.length-1];
//The problem is defined test if module is loaded, not if module exist
if(require.defined("Module/"+Getter[0]+"/"+Getter[1]+"/"+Getter[1]")){
  requirejs(["Module/"+Getter[0]+"/"+Getter[1]+"/"+Getter[1]],function (Module) {

                        Module.Main();

  });
  
}
```

How can I load a module only if it exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Does a module exist?" is an ambiguous question. You've discovered that `require.define` check whether a module is loaded, but what *you* want is to check whether calling `require` with some module name will actually load a module or not. **RequireJS provides no way to perform this check *before* loading a module.**

What you can do is just try to load the module and provide an errback to record the fact that the module is not available:

```
require(["someModule"], function (someModule) {
  // If we get here the module exists. Use it.
}, 
function (err) {
  // This is the errback. We get here if the module could not be loaded.
  // Perform whatever alternative is needed.
});
```

Comment: Perfect , it's possible to use promise with requirejs ?

Comment: RequireJS itself does not use promises. In the past when I've had to use promise with RequireJS, I've put `require` calls into `new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {` and got promises that way. There's [Alameda](https://github.com/requirejs/alameda) that works with promises, and is made by the same author as RequireJS, but I've not used it.